# auto printing documents in a folder

Tags: vbscript

im very new to all of this so please stay with me here

id like something that will automatically print everything placed in a specific folder

i found a bit of code here:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/83142-automatically-print-files-placed-in-folder

that seems to kind of do what i want

```
TargetFolder = "Z:\Desktop\work"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder) 
Set colItems = objFolder.Items 
For Each objItem In colItems 
objItem.InvokeVerbEx ("Print") 
objItem.InvokeVerbEx ("delete") 
Next
```

iv added the

```
objItem.InvokeVerbEx ("delete")
```

and saved it as .VBS but it's not doing exactly what i want, what id like is for it to print only word documents and then delete them, now i tried to put

```
sleep 10
```

after print to give it some time to open the document and print it before deleting it but i kept giving me an error

also is there a way to get it to trigger on its own every time a word document is dropped into the folder?

thank you

Comment: Instead of saving-printing-deleting, why don't you print and *not* save or delete?

Comment: it's not us that's saving it, it's a program that generates the document and saves it in to a folder

Comment: alright, I see - also, [tag:vba] or [tag:vbs]?  (Similar, but not interchangeable.)  Perhaps `Kill` is the command you're after, but I'm not clear on which language you're using, and where.